# PHP - If URL has this in it, do not show div

Tags: php, javascript, url, host

I am trying to find the best way to have a DIV be hidden if the url is something. For example I have 2 sites using the same template but only 1 of those sites I want to display something.

So site A is domain.com
Site B is site.domain.com

I want it so if site.domain.com is where people are at then do not show DIV ID="hide".  I also need it to have this work for not just that specific URL but for anything that comes after it so site.domain.com/aboutus.php, site.domain.com/contact.php etc....

I would like to do this with PHP or JS.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: You will need to do this with PHP if the DIV needs to be hidden for security purposes. If you are hiding the DIV for usability reasons, JS will suffice.

Comment: But these are two separate sites, running on separate databases, correct? The only common thing is the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check `HTTP_HOST`:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'site.domain.com'){
        echo '<div>contents</div>'; // display div, he is not on site.domain.com
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do something like:

```
<php if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.com'): ?>
<div>This is example.com</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div>This is NOT example.com</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I think you'd really be better off creating some sort of site1_settings.php that gets included on every page in one site, and then site2_settings.php that gets included in the second. For one thing, this will make it much easier to test your code locally.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for this.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "site") !== FALSE)
{
  // The user is on site.domain.com
}
else
{
  // The user is on domain.com
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my javascript implementation. Note: jQuery

```
if(window.location.indexOf("textinurl"))
{
    $('#DivId').hide();

}
```

Comment: Why use jQuery, when a simple `document.getElementById('DivId').style.display = 'none';` would do just as well?

Comment: Either way works. jQuery is great for clean code and extensibility. If all OP ever needs to do with this code block is hide the div, you're correct.